# ionic 4 build error when serving with --devapp

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have deployed ionic4+ angular app which runs successfully on browser but when try to run on devapp it gives following error. The angular build fails when i provide --devapp flag to ionic serve.

```
C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client>ionic serve --devapp
> ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100 --cordova-mock --consolelogs --consolelogs-port=53703
[ng] Project target does not exist.
[ng] Error: Project target does not exist.
[ng]     at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget (C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:15:19)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:175:55)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:216:35)
[ng]     at RunCommand.run (C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js:14:25)
[ng]     at RunCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Surendra\Desktop\googlevision\googlevision\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:137:39)
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ng]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
[ng]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[ng]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "postbuild-prod": "bread-compressor dist/app",
    "serve-dist": "ws --hostname localhost -d dist/app -p 1234 -o --log.format stats",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.4.2",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.1",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "2.0.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/node": "12.0.4",
    "bread-compressor-cli": "1.0.7",
    "codelyzer": "5.0.1",
    "local-web-server": "2.6.1",
    "tslint": "5.17.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

P.S.- This app works fine on browser but failed to run with `ionic serve --devapp`. 
Tried updating `@ionic/angular-toolkit` but still giving error.

Comment: Please try npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue, it turns out that this error is very misleading if you don't know what you're looking at, i was convinced that it was an error with ionic, it turns out that when you use --devapp it uses a different "architect"... this architect is actually called ionic-cordova-serve, which relies on ionic-cordova-build.

I was missing both of these architect rules in my project/app when i moved my code in.

My "projects" name in my angular.json file is "tech", this is what mine looks now that it's working now.

```
    "tech": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "apps/tech",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/tech/src",
      "prefix": "tech",
      "architect": {
        ... (build, serve, test, ect are here)
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tech:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "tech:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "tech:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "tech:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "tech:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "tech:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

be sure to change the `tech:<item>` to your project/app name.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this. Answer may be here.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3836#issuecomment-472194895
https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/devapp